# How does changing torch dytpe affect performance and learning?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to modify test different dtypes for pytorch, right now I'm using torch.float32 as it is the default value, would the code and the neural network training and inference perform better using torch.float16 or even torch.int16 if it's possible?

Comment: The best answer to any optimization question is to grab a stopwatch and try both methods.

Answer (score 0):

A field of study called quantization is dedicated to this to reduce model size so that it can be used for inference on edge devices.

What it really doing is converting 32 bit weights to 8 bit weights which reduces the size of model but accuracy also takes the hit since when values are passed through activation, they change.

Quantization can be done while training as well as post training. Many prefer to do post training and then calibrate using test data for large models that are already built

For in-training quantization, I would suggest you look into quantization aware training available on both tensorflow and pytorch